# List Files in a Subdirectory and get Relative Paths only with Windows Command Line

Tags: windows, command-line, directory-listing

I want to use the Windows command line to list files with path.

For example:

```
~\folder1
  \1.jpg
  \2.jpg
~\folder2
  \01.jpg
  \02.jpg
```

I want the output to be similar to the relative paths rather than the full path though:

```
.\folder1\1.jpg
.\foler1\2.jpg
```

When I use `DIR /S /B *.jpg > list.txt` that lists the full path like `C:\download\folder\folder1\1.jpg`, I only need it to list the relative path like `.\folder1\1.jpg`...

Using the Linux Command Line of `find ./ -iname *.jpg > list.txt`, gives me the expected result but I need a solution that'll work like this with Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Using Windows command line to List files with subdirectory**
>
> I want to output: .\folder1\1.jpg,.\foler1\2.jpg....
>
> I know if we use dir /s/b *.jpg > list.txt that will get something
>   like C:\download\folder\folder1\1.jpg, I don't want to that, I just
>   need .\folder1\1.jpg

**Variable Clarification (below)**

- Where the logic below is `FOR %X IN ("folder1","Folder2")` or `SET
  Folders=("Folder1","Folder2","Folder3","Folder4")`you will put your
  `"Folder1"`,`"Folder2"`, and so on just like that with the double
  quotes and commas for each folder name you want to look for and list
  the `./Foldername/file.jpg` to the file you are appending the echo'd
  output.
- For the **Command Line Copy Example**, you will want to do a `CD /D C:\Path` to the parent directory where the subfolders where the `.JPG` files exist as that logic is implicit assuming you're in the parent directory to find those child subfolders and the filetypes/extensions they contain.
- For the other examples, you will just plug in the parent directory that contains all the child subfolders where the `.JPG` files exist in the `SET ParentDir=` value and everything should work otherwise as expected.
- The other variables that are `SET` should be self explanatory I assume as those are named pretty close to what they mean but let me know if you need further clarification otherwise.

### Command Line Copy Example

```
FOR %X IN ("folder1","Folder2") DO FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %F IN ('DIR /B /A-D ".\%~X\*.jpg"') DO ECHO .\%~X\%~F>>C:\Path\Log.txt
```

### Set Variables Command Line Copy Example

*(Use the below to set your folder names and file extensions for the `DIR` command. Also plug in the parent directory full path where the subfolders you want to append in that format to the text file is located.)*

```
SET FileType=*.jpg
SET ParentDir=C:\Users\Name\Desktop
SET Folders=("Folder1","Folder2","Folder3","Folder4")
SET LogFile=C:\Path\LogFile.txt

CD /D "%ParentDir%"
FOR %X IN %Folders% DO FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %F IN ('DIR /B /A-D ".\%~X\%FileType%"') DO ECHO .\%~X\%~F>>"%LogFile%"
```

### Batch Script Example with Setting Variables

```
@ECHO ON
SET FileType=*.jpg
SET ParentDir=C:\Users\Name\Desktop
SET Folders=("Folder1","Folder2","Folder3","Folder4")
SET LogFile=C:\Path\LogFile.txt

CD /D "%ParentDir%"
FOR %%X IN %Folders% DO FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%F IN (

    'DIR /B /A-D ".\%%~X\%FileType%"'

) DO ECHO .\%%~X\%%~F>>"%LogFile%"
GOTO EOF
```

### Further Reading and Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)
- [**FOR**](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [**SET**](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html)

Comment: A big weakness of this approach is that the list of subdirectories to consider is hard-coded.  There's a better approach given here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12209020/2019892

Answer (score 3):

### FOR POWERSHELL - ONE LINER

You can also use PowerShell:

```
PS> Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Resolve-Path -Relative
```

Or from cmd prompt or in a batch file:

```
powershell.exe "Get-ChildItem -Recurse . | Resolve-Path -Relative"
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for function to list the relative path only.

Here some alternative solutions...

(Please replace %cd% with your start path, e.g. C:\download\folder )

**List all sub-directories and files with relative path to a specific start path:**

```
@echo off
SET "StartPath=%cd%"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /ON /S "!StartPath!"') DO (
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=%%f"
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=!SubDirsAndFiles:%StartPath%=!"
    ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles! 
)
```

**List selected file types only with the relative path to a specific start path (e.g. *.jpg, *.png):**

```
@echo off
SET "StartPath=%cd%"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /ON /S "!StartPath!\*.jpg" "!StartPath!\*.png"') DO (
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=%%f"
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=!SubDirsAndFiles:%StartPath%=!"
    ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles! 
)
```

**List all sub-directories and files with relative path to a specific start path (paths ends with \):**

```
@echo off
SET "StartPath=%cd%"

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /B /ON /S "!StartPath!"') DO (
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=%%f"
    set "SubDirsAndFiles=!SubDirsAndFiles:%StartPath%=!"
    IF EXIST "!StartPath!\!SubDirsAndFiles!\" (
        REM Echo This is a folder...
        ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles!\
    ) ELSE (
        REM Echo This is a file...
        ECHO !SubDirsAndFiles!
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

One line BATCH command:

```
for /r %x in (*) do set _curFilePath=%~x& call echo .\%_curFilePath:%CD%\=%
```

In a batch file (.bat or .cmd):

```
for /r %%x in (*) do set _curFilePath=%%~x& call echo .\%%_curFilePath:%CD%\=%%
```

"call" is used to temporarily mimic a dynamic allocation.
Change "echo" by the command you want.